# use nth-child() selector to change JUST row background

Tags: css, css-selectors

I am trying to setup a table that will have X number of rows, with each row's background color set by ID (or class, either way... this is to identify each row's category).  On top of that, I would like to use nth-child to change the opacity for the background of each even row, so that if there are a lot of rows for a particular category, the user can easily skim the table.  I setup some code on JSFiddle, but the entire row's content (text, background, border) is affected, not just the background (which makes sense, of course).

```
#a {   background:lightblue; }
#b {   background:orange; }
#c {   background:lightgreen; }
.row:nth-child(even) {
  opacity: .60;
}
```

[Full code here](https://jsfiddle.net/chipsterva69/fns1prz0/)

So far, all of the solutions I have found either don't address the different row background colors, or involve a convoluted use of multiple layers that create issues with the nth-child selector.  It also appears most of the answers for this are from awhile ago, so I am hoping that there is a more recent solution.

Any help or advice is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/demo doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: Alos, if it's an issue of the background having opacity, **use an RGBA color**

Comment: @Paulie_D - thanks for the info on the link.  I was wondering why the Stack Snippet window popped up...  makes sense once spelled out.  I will keep that in mind for next time.  And I had already tried the RBGA setup, but that in and of itself didn't correct the issue, so I flipped my code back to hex.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Opacity is affecting all of the properties of the `row` because that's what you're selecting. To only affect the background color, you can change your `.row:nth-child(event)` selector to the following CSS:

```
.row.a:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: rgb(173, 216, 230, .6);
}
.row.b:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: rgb(255, 165, 0, .6);
}
.row.c:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: rgb(144, 238, 144, .6);
}
```

You should adjust your HTML to use classes instead of IDs (see https://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-id-and-class/ for more info):

```
<div class="container">
  <div id="table">
    <div class="row a">
      Row 1 / Cat 1
    </div>
    <div class="row a">
      Row 2 / Cat 1
    </div>
    <div class="row a">
      Row 3 / Cat 1
    </div>
    <div class="row b">
      Row 4 / Cat 2
    </div>
    <div class="row b">
      Row 5 / Cat 2
    </div>
    <div class="row c">
      Row 6 / Cat 3
    </div>
    <div class="row c">
      Row 7 / Cat 3
    </div>
    <div class="row c">
      Row 8 / Cat 3
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And then your final CSS would be:

```
.container {   padding: 20px; }
.row {   padding: 5px 15px;  border-bottom: 1px solid black; }
.a {   background-color: rgb(173, 216, 230, 1); /*lightblue*/ }
.b {   background-color: rgb(255, 165, 0, 1); /*orange*/ }
.c {   background-color: rgb(144, 238, 144, 1); /*lightgreen*/ }
.row:nth-child(1) {   border-top: 1px solid black; }

.row.a:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: rgb(173, 216, 230, .6); /*lightblue less opaque*/
}
.row.b:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: rgb(255, 165, 0, .6); /*orange less opaque*/
}
.row.c:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: rgb(144, 238, 144, .6); /*lightgreen less opaque*/
}
```

See https://jsfiddle.net/WOUNDEDStevenJones/u46nkjb0/1/ for a working version

Comment: very nicely done. Opaque = translucent. :)

Comment: My bad! Fixed comment to "less opaque".

Comment: Worked like a charm - thanks for the info on the code simplification and reference link, and thanks for the spelled out code.  Looking at it now, I could put this into SASS/LESS and make the color values a single variable, further simplifying.  Thanks again!

Comment: Less opaque = translucent! Translucent covers everything between opaque and transparent. :)